# Crawlera: 407 "Bad Auth" error message

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapinghub

Using Crawlera's sample code for a GET request with a proxy.

```
import requests

url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"
proxy_host = "proxy.crawlera.com"
proxy_port = "8010"
proxy_auth = "<APIKEY>:" # Make sure to include ':' at the end
proxies = {
      "https": "https://{}@{}:{}/".format(proxy_auth, proxy_host, proxy_port),
      "http": "http://{}@{}:{}/".format(proxy_auth, proxy_host, proxy_port)
}

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
```

I get a 407 Bad Proxy Auth error. I've tripled check that the API_KEY is correct.

Response headers:

```
{
   'Proxy-Connection': 'close',
   'Proxy-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Crawlera"',
   'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
   'Connection': 'close',
   'Date': 'Mon, 26 Mar 2018 11:18:05 GMT',
   'X-Crawlera-Error': 'bad_proxy_auth',
   'X-Crawlera-Version': '1.32.0-07c786'
}
```

Requests is already updated.

```
$ pip freeze |grep requests
requests==2.8.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by adding a `Proxy-Authorization` header.

```
proxy_auth  = "<APIKEY>:"
headers = {
   # other headers ...
   "Proxy-Authorization": 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(proxy_auth)
}

proxies = {
      "https": "https://{}:{}/".format(proxy_host, proxy_port),
      "http": "http://{}:{}/".format(proxy_host, proxy_port)
}


r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, gives the error message `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` for the `base64.b64encode(proxy_auth)` code bit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the 'crawlera' way you can try upgrading your requests client:

```
pip install requests --upgrade
```

I had the same problem, and your solution worked, but then after further searches I found [this](https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/discussions/topics/22000008783) solution:

Upgrading to `requests` client to **2.19**... worked for me, and I could keep using  the Crawlera sample script.